# If $v \in Ker(A)$ does that mean $v \in Ker(\Sigma)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, svd

Using SVD, if $v \in Ker(A)$ does that mean $v \in Ker(\Sigma)$?
How can I proof this, if so?

Comment: No, it is very much untrue, because $A$ is obtained by multiplying $\Sigma$ (also) *on the right* by some invertible matrix.

Comment: Given $A = U \Sigma V^T$, $U$ and $V$ being invertible doesn't make this statement true? Wouldnt the kernel of $U$ and $V$ be $0$? and thus what's left is $\Sigma$?

Comment: $\ker \Sigma$ and $\ker A$ have the same dimension, but since there's that $V^*$ in between they are not the same set. Same thing happens for $\operatorname{range}A$ and $\operatorname{range}\Sigma$ because of $U$.